# Scale image in imageview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview

I am trying to size the image to match parent width but i cant get it to work after hours of research. Attaching image of xml and view.

How it looks like:

[image: wrong view]

How it should look:

[image: right view]

Or should I consider using CardView to get the visuals instead?

Comment: Not sure how your setting the image you can either use the src attribute of the image view or set it in code, as for the image view you need to do two things first set the size of the image view with the width and height attributes and second set the scale type see this here https://abhiandroid.com/ui/scaletype-imageview-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it using CardView instead!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `android:scaleType="fitXY"` or `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` in your ImageView?